# Null Pointer Admob Adrequest

Tags: android, admob, andengine, google-play-services, adview

Im having some problems setting Admob up,
First off here is my code this is all under the onCreateEngine method:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here is the xml part:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

When i tried setting adsize as an xml attribute i get an error that says
"Required xml attribute adSize was missing"
So i tried setting it programmatically, however i have another issue.
Whenever i call `adView.loadAd(adRequest);` i get a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you using AndEngine. Override onSetContentView() and put code inside this. Something like this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onSetContentView() {
        super.onSetContentView();

    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: yea this seems to fix my problem with the null pointer thank you :], now i got a new problem though. The add still gives me "Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing" i also get alot of things that say `The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.` i checked my project and it seems fine to me. google-play-services_lib  is still added as a library.

Comment: If you're setting the adSize in code, you'll need to create your AdView in code too.

Answer (score 1):

[com.google.ads.AdView : The following classes could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604618/com-google-ads-adview-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found)

at this page reVerse says ;

"Since you're using the Google Play Services you have to change the class from

com.google.ads.AdView

to

com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView"