# com.google.ads.AdView : The following classes could not be found

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to integrate admob ads in my application but I am getting this error.

"The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.ads.AdView "

Main XML Layout Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"    
    ads:adUnitId="My_Add_Id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Mainifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solutionproviders.bajiascooking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16" 
              android:minSdkVersion="9"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>     


        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am using Google play services for adding ads.

[image: Library added in android folder]

[image: Library in Private and Android Dependencies]

[image: Error as shown in XML Layout]

I am checked all the solutions provided on Stakeoverflow but none worked for me. Please suggest me a solution. Any other info will be provided but I think I have provided enough info for the problem.

Comment: Please Update Your PlayStore Lib or Added Jar file on admob in to your Project

Comment: i your playStoreLib There is No admob class So please Update Your Lib Or Go to Google Admob download Admob.jar Added In Lib folder of Project

Comment: How to do that? Help me please.

Comment: Download Jar fril and Added in Project Lib Folder http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/DownloadGoogleAdMobAdsSdk601jar.htm

Comment: do I have to add the admob sdk in Order & Export?

Comment: I have pasted the jar fil in .libs folder but it doesn't helped. :(

Comment: post your mail id i will send to playstore Lib That Contant Admob Class use this PlayStore lib Instant of Your Lib

Comment: it doesn't worked @Naveen .. now error in xml layout are : The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 9
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/ads/AdSize.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @4: ifne

Comment: my email id: solutionprovider7442@gmail.com

Comment: Please check your ADT Veridon On AndroidSDKManager i m Using ADT 23.0.2 Have u this adt

Comment: I have adt version 23.0.2.1259578

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the **Google Play Services** you have to change the class from

```
com.google.ads.AdView
```

to

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

**Do not use the AdMob SDK** - this one is deprecated as of August 1st. You won't be able to publish an *.apk in the Play Store if you're using this outdated SDK. Admob is now part of the Google Play Services and it's mandatory to use this one. Read more in the [Docs (Google Mobile Ads SDK)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).

Comment: That doesn't helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these 3 steps:

1. add a dependency in gradle app level.
2. add xml in the yourfile.xml
3. java code in onCreate Method

Dependency :
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'`